# Is it ironic to write on a dry-erase board with a permanent marker?

Tags: irony

There is a dry-erase board.  It has a shopping list on it.  At the bottom of the shopping list, I added "Dry-erase Markers".  But I did this in permanent marker, because we were all out of dry-erase markers.

Is this ironic?  Why or why not?

Comment: It's a good story, and it's going to be around for a while, so you might as well say it was irony and not merely a mistake. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From dictionary.com

" Ironic literature exploits, in addition to the rhetorical figure, such devices as character development, situation, and plot to stress the paradoxical nature of reality or the contrast between an ideal and actual condition, set of circumstances, etc., frequently in such a way as to stress the absurdity present in the contradiction between substance and form"

Since the event contrasts ideal and actual, I would say it is ironic.